# My img div is floating in the other div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get my bootstrap `img-responsive` to get to the bottom of the div, but it no matter what I do, it won't move. I've tried altering the `img-resposive` CSS file setting `height:`to `0`and `bottom:`to `0` but it doesn't fix the problem.
 I'm new to this and probably missing something out, so please be tolerant.

```css
<!--this is the bootstrap.css file -->

.img-responsive,
    .thumbnail > img,
    .thumbnail a > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!--and this is the html -->

<div class="col-md-9 hidden-sm">
    <img src="img/valencia.png" class="img-responsive animated fadeInRight" alt="mockup">
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried giving it `position: absolute;`??

Comment: As @Sushil said, the `bottom` property won't work without `position: absolute;` set.

Comment: @Webster19.98 try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ce20kfjL/

Comment: I would advise against editing the `bootstrap.css`. You should write styles that override the bootstrap styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comments mention you **should not** update the bootstrap css file directly. You should create your own custom CSS style sheet and update that instead!

Based on the code you provided (which isn't much) there are a couple of ways to make your image show at the bottom of the container.

CSS using `table-cell`

```
.yourcustomclassname {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

CSS using `absolute` positioning:

```
.yourcustomclassname {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.yourcustomclassname img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

HTML will be the same for either:

```
<div class="col-md-9 hidden-sm yourcustomclassname">
    <img src="img/valencia.png" class="img-responsive animated fadeInRight" alt="mockup">
</div>
```

Hopefully this is enough to get you started based on the code you provided.

Comment: Thanks, used the `table-cell` scheme and it worked just fine. Also, thanks for explaining that can't alter the bootstrap file.